# PHP session variables not passing successfully

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm making my first foray into sessions in PHP. I want, for example, to create a link to a page called phonemessearch2.php that loads that page and sets the variable phon1 to "M", phon3 to "L", phon4 to "IY". amd umatch to "umatch". I therefore link to this URL:

phonemessearch2.php?phon1=M&phon3=L&phon4=IY&umatch=umatch

Here is the code in the target page:

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");
session_start();

//submitted form variable definitions

if(isset($_POST['umatch']))
{
    $umatch = $_POST['umatch'];
} else {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['umatch']) )
    {
        $umatch = '';
    } else {
        $umatch = $_SESSION['umatch'];
    }
} 
$_SESSION['umatch'] = $umatch;


if(isset($_POST['phon1']))
{
    $phon1 = $_POST['phon1'];
} else {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['phon1']) )
    {
        $phon1 = '';
    } else {
        $phon1 = $_SESSION['phon1'];
    }
} 
$_SESSION['phon1'] = $phon1;

if(isset($_POST['phon2']))
{
    $phon2 = $_POST['phon2'];
} else {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['phon2']) )
    {
        $phon2 = '';
    } else {
        $phon2 = $_SESSION['phon2'];
    }
} 
$_SESSION['phon2'] = $phon2;

if(isset($_POST['phon3']))
{
    $phon3 = $_POST['phon3'];
} else {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['phon3']) )
    {
        $phon3 = '';
    } else {
        $phon3 = $_SESSION['phon3'];
    }
} 
$_SESSION['phon3'] = $phon3;

if(isset($_POST['phon4']))
{
    $phon4 = $_POST['phon4'];
} else {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['phon4']) )
    {
        $phon4 = '';
    } else {
        $phon4 = $_SESSION['phon4'];
    }
} 
$_SESSION['phon4'] = $phon4;

if(isset($_POST['phon5']))
{
    $phon5 = $_POST['phon5'];
} else {
    if( !isset($_SESSION['phon5']) )
    {
        $phon5 = '';
    } else {
        $phon5 = $_SESSION['phon5'];
    }
}
```

When the page loads, it is not incorporating the variable values from the URL. All the variables are blank. How can I make them stick?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with your sessions - the variables in a URL like `phonemessearch2.php?phon1=M&phon3=L&phon4=IY&umatch=umatch` would be in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.